# No search results after reseting index on Google Mini Appliance

Tags: google, search, gsa

A few days ago I reset the index (following instructions from help) on a client's Google Mini Appliance after a complete site redesign. Of course at first there were no search results. But at this point the crawl stats seems to be similar to their previous counts. However the search still yields no results.

I have been trying to diagnose the issue. Unfortunately I didn't setup the appliance and am not that familiar with its administration. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried:

- Restarting the system
- Switching back to the default collection
- Switching back to the default front-end

Feel free to take a look at the site: http://floydmemorial.com/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have not used this for a while, but appliance we used pulled logs from our web servers via transfer and we had to tell it to parse them manually. This was back in the day so things might have changed.

If you are still using that process I would advise checking the parsing scripts/permission/data of logs.

Your next best bet is logging into the shell of the appliance and looking at /var/log/ for any clues.

Comment: How would I shell into the mini? That is to say where could I find the connectivity information? I have the web admin credentials.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/remote_access/remote_access.html#directssh

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an issue with collections and the Site parameter.  When I search for "info:[URL]" on your site, the examples I've tried (such as "info:http://floydmemorial.com/patients/") return the correct result. The info: tag ignores collection settings.

So the Mini has apparently crawled and indexed your new site.  Google's troubleshooting tips for [Determining Why a Particular Document Is Not in the Search Results](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/68/troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#NotInResults) may apply, especially the following:

> **Are you searching within a collection or subcollection?**
>   Use the Status and Reports > Crawl Diagnostics page to view information for a specific collection. If you have a default_collection that contains all URLs, change the site parameter in the query to read site=default_collection. Verify that the patterns for defining the collection match the URL of the web page.
>   **Is the document tagged with default_collection?**
>   Is the document tagged with any collection? ***Try removing the site parameter and its value from the search request.*** *[Emphasis added]* By default, the value site=default_collection is applied to all documents in the index, but the value for the site parameter can be changed. If the patterns for that collection have been modified, searching without the site parameter will that ensure all documents in the index are potential search results, even if they are not tagged with default_collection.

Besides the [Mini documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/50/index.html), you can search & ask the experts at  http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Search-Appliance/.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that `info:` returns a result for the page. However, what has this really proven? Also I have removed the parameters from the request - http://search.floydmemorial.com/search?q=patients still doesn't yield any results.

Comment: Proven it's crawled the URL on your new site, I imagine :). At right end of the blue bar on admin pages, have you tried the Test Center and chosen different Front Ends and Collections to see if any combo works?  Also, in Serving > Front Ends, Edit the front end you're using, and check the different tabs including Remove URLs.  You might try using default_frontend after clicking "Restore Default" on the "Output Format" tab.

Comment: Fair. It was nice seeing some result show up. Unfortunately none of the combinations seem to work in the Test Center. I've verified that the crawl is running and there are 50,000+ pages successfully crawled according to the Crawl Reports. There has to be some simple, overlooked reason why the results don't show up.

Comment: If you haven't yet posted your scenario on the Google group, I'd do it.  High-end expertise, free.  Might also run a query log report (makes you name it first, oddly) and look for clues in the detailed query strings it shows.